# Ojdbc driver error

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g, ojdbc

I'm trying to optimize the performance of querys from my Java application to the Oracle database, because the same querys doing by sql developer tool are faster than by the java application. 
I have two different database (one to test/developer and the other for production).

The developer database version is: 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

The production database version is: 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit

My java application was using ojdbc14 driver, that works fine for both databases, but the performance querys are working slowly. So after investigate, I read that a good way to start to improve the performance was using the correct ojdbc driver in the java application (according the database version). So I downloaded the ojdbc6 driver (for 11.2.0.3 oracle version). That work fine in the developer database, but i have the next error when im trying to connect the production database:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;

I tried with different ojdbc driver version (5, 6), but I get the same error, in the production database only.

Some help?

Sorry my english.

Regards.

Edit 1:

@CSK

I'm using Spring MVC, here is my ApplitacionContext xml for the database connection:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceDataStage" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.datastage.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.datastage.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.datastage.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.datastage.password}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.datastage.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.datastage.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.datastage.maxStatements}" />
```

Comment: try oracle upc connection pool. and you need to paste the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're some thing wrong with your classpath in production. So, if possible, try to add jar file (orai18n.jar) directly to your project and recheck again.
In my case, it worked & Hope it help!

Comment: Yes, I was using a wrong orai18n jar. I downloaded it again from oracle web and now It works fine. Thanks.

Regards